# How could I get the text is inside of a span which has no ID but a class

Tags: c#, .net

I was testing WebBrowser, but there's no method to getElemments by class, but by tag.

I have something like this.

html:

```
<div class="Justnames">
<span class="name">Georgia</span>
</div>
```

So i'd like to get the string "Georgia", which is inside of that span.

I tried:

```
Var example = Nav.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
```

But it return null, and I've no idea why.

Sorry my english and thanks a lot of the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
   var elementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
   elementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
   foreach (var element in elementCollection)
   {
        if (element.OuterHtml.Contains("name"))
            // we reach here, we get <span class="example"
    }
```

Or:

```
foreach (var element in elementCollection)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "name")
    // we reach here, we get <span class="example"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery :

```
var test = $(".name").text();
alert(test):
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged "C#" and ".net" i assume you have a aspx page and try to access it from server code. To access it from server side you have to add the `runat="server"` tag to the span:

```
<span class="name" runat="server">Georgia</span>
```

Otherwise you only can access it from client side (JavaScript)

Comment: I think OP want to access the element from C# code. There is a `WebBrowser` control in .Net framework

Comment: Yep, but WebBrowser has not a method in order to get the innertext inside of the class... How could I get "Georgia" string, throught c#.net? I mean, something like "scraping", sorry my english >.<